# How to make a pointer member const'able

Tags: c++, c

Ok so this might be a simple question but I couldn't find an answer. Let's say I have the following struct:

```cpp
struct Bytes {
    uint8_t* buffer;
    uint32_t length;
};
```

And I try to initialize it like this:

```cpp
const uint8_t buffer[] = "Hello";
const uint32_t length = sizeof(buffer);
const Bytes bytes = { buffer, length };
```

Then it will not compile becouse the buffer I passed is `cosnt uint8_t*` and the struct expects just `uint8_t*` even if the whole `Bytes` struct is const. I could make the `buffer` member a `const uint8_t*` but that would break some other code where I actually want the bytes to be mutable. So I guess my question is:

**Is there a way to make a pointer member retain the same mutability as the structure?**

Comment: C or C++?  They are not the same language, and if you're using C and not C++,  your question was closed because you mistagged it with C++.

Comment: If you want to use pointers to const and non-const buffers, how would you know whether you are allowed to modify the buffer when you use that struct in your functions?

Comment: @AndrewHenle I'm using c++ and i tagged it with c as well becouse i thought there might be a c solution compatible with c++. Anyway, it turns out someone already asked this on stackoverflow and I just couldn't find it becouse I didn't know how to word it properly. Now someone tagged my question as duplicate and linked to the one already answered so problem solved :)